# Evaluating $2x^3+2x^2-7x+72$ where $x= \frac{3-5i}{2} $

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

So I have to find the value of  : 
$$2x^3+2x^2-7x+72$$ at $$x= \frac{3-5i}{2} $$
Where $i$ stands for $\sqrt{-1}$.
I know the obvious approach would be to substitute the value of $x$ in the equation, but the equation gets extremely messy in that process. Is there any easier or quicker approach for the sum.

P.s. The answer is $4$.

Comment: Do synthetic division.

Comment: @Masacroso sorry. My bad

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Please explain it. I have done it for other questions, but I can't understand how to apply it in the case of a complex polynomial

Comment: Write it as $72 - x\big( 7 - 2x(1+x)\big)$ and work from the inside out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $\frac{3-5i}{2}$ is the solution of $2x^2-6x+17 = 0$.

Then, $$2x^3 + 2x^2-7x+72 = x(2x^2-6x+17) + 4(2x^2-6x+17) + 4 = 4.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x= \frac{3-5i}{2}$$ $$x^2=x \times x=-4-\frac{15 i}{2}$$ $$x^3=x \times x^2=-\frac{99}{4}-\frac{5 i}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the polynomial remainder theorem $f(\frac{3-5i}{2})$ is simply the remainder we get when we divide $f(x)$ by $x-\frac{3-5i}{2}$. So perform [synthetic](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jJp5UmSEGxk) division, which I think is easier.